# Airbnb API - Action not found - Using cURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to connect to Airbnb and return my reservations from it.
I was able to successfully login using cURL, but I can't retrieve the reservations.

The reservations URL: http://airbnbapi.org/#get-host-messages

As you can see the HTTP Method is `GET`, `client_id` must be passed in the URL and `X-Airbnb-OAuth-Token` in the headers (after login).

After perform the cURL on login I receive the following header output (by using the function `CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT`):

```
POST /v1/authorize HTTP/1.1
Host: api.airbnb.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 511
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------aa1ew132ff32wca9
```

With the 200 HTTP code.

After login, I perform the cURL on reservations and I get:

```
GET /v2/threads?client_id=MyApiKey&_limit=10 HTTP/1.1
Host: api.airbnb.com
Accept: */*

{"error_code":404,"error_type":"invalid_action","error_message":"Action not found."}
```

With the following code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.airbnb.com/v2/threads?client_id=MyApiKey&_limit=10');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-Airbnb-OAuth-Token: ' . $MyAccessToken));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

$response   = curl_exec($ch);
$http       = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$headerout  = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($headerout);

return array($http, $response);
```

If I use the [hurl.it](https://www.hurl.it/?url=https%3A//api.airbnb.com/v2/threads&method=GET&headers=%7B%22X-Airbnb-OAuth-Token%22%3A%5B%229wled6f39td9vksj280twe10w%22%5D%7D&args=%7B%22_offset%22%3A%5B%220%22%5D%2C%22locale%22%3A%5B%22en-US%22%5D%2C%22_format%22%3A%5B%22for_mobile_inbox%22%5D%2C%22currency%22%3A%5B%22USD%22%5D%2C%22_limit%22%3A%5B%2210%22%5D%2C%22role%22%3A%5B%22host%22%5D%2C%22client_id%22%3A%5B%223092nxybyb0otqw18e8nh5nty%22%5D%7D) with my values it works without any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**.

The problem was that my `return` should be decoding the `$response` as JSON and instead I'm retrieving it as plain text and therefore I'm not able to get the `access_token` parameter.

And since `error_reporting` is turned off, I didn't see that `access_token` was empty.

```
return array($http, json_decode($response));
```